# SQL Server : Invalid Cursor State when SHOWPLAN turned on

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to figure out why I am getting an 'Invalid Cursor State' error when I turn on the `SHOWPLAN` functionality in my SQL client.

The code I run is below:

```
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;

Select * 
From Sys.Objects

SET SHOWPLAN_XML OFF;
```

[This is the error I get when I run this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtXRP.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you put `GO` after each of the  commands, creating 3 separate batches,  do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your error.

```
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;
GO

Select * From Sys.Objects
GO

SET SHOWPLAN_XML OFF;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a Cursor which is left open.  You'll need to remember to [DEALLOCATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188782.aspx) the cursor (the code of which is not part of your question)

> DEALLOCATE { { [ GLOBAL ] cursor_name } | @cursor_variable_name }

Because the open cursor code is not provided, I cannot tell you the parameters to use.

I believe this will help [close all cursors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186256.aspx):

```
-- Declare a cursor variable to hold the cursor output variable  
-- from sp_cursor_list.  
DECLARE @Report CURSOR;  

-- Execute sp_cursor_list into the cursor variable.  
EXEC master.dbo.sp_cursor_list @cursor_return = @Report OUTPUT,  
      @cursor_scope = 2;  

-- Fetch all the rows from the sp_cursor_list output cursor.  
FETCH NEXT from @Report;  
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)  
BEGIN  
   FETCH NEXT from @Report;  
END  

-- Close and deallocate the cursor from sp_cursor_list.  
CLOSE @Report;  
DEALLOCATE @Report;  
GO
```

On top of that you have another error.

> Msg 1067, Level 15, State 1, Line 0 The SET SHOWPLAN statements must
>   be the only statements in the batch.

As the error suggests, you need to break it up into different batches.  **SET SHOWPLAN** must be in alone in the batch.  There are several commands which require their own batch

Try this:

```
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;      
GO

SELECT   * FROM   Sys.Objects;      
GO

SET SHOWPLAN_XML OFF;      
GO
```